# Textmate TODO not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I am trying to use Textmate's TODO bundle :

```
// TODO: change click to tap
/*
  TODO change click to tap
*/
```

Neither of these markups are captured... How can I specify a TODO in JavaScript?

Comment: I just tested the exact same syntax as above in TM 2.0-alpha.9489 and didn't have any problems capturing the TODO's at all.

Comment: I have the same problem with ERB files.

Comment: Same problem in Ruby files in 2.0-alpha.9497. Tried the suggestion to use `todo[TAB]`, but that doesn't work either, even after fixing the block comment delimiters.

Comment: I have to assume you installed the Todo bundle... Right?

Answer (score 0):

To be sure of using the correct syntax, just use the Todo bundle `todoTAB` shortcut.

If it doens't show your todos, try moving to the File Browser and navigating to the root of the project. That usually fixes this for me.